# Can't select all dates on DatePicker dialog on small screens on Android API 23

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-theme, android-dialog, android-datepicker

When displaying a date picker dialog on small screens (f.e. Nexus S) on Android 6 (API 23) not all dates can be selected. The row on the bottom is cut off.

[image: Android API 23]

This not only happens on our app but also in other apps like Google Keep.

On Android 7 (API 24) the layout for date picker dialogs has changed so that the problem does not occur any more.

[image]

How can this be fixed? I know that different styles/themes can be used for each API level but I could not manage to figure out which one solves the issue.

Here are some code snippets from `styles.xml`

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="AppCompatDialogStyle"
    parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#E8AD00</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find a better solution than using another theme (Holo?) for API < 24.